# numpy.argmin is giving me the maximum element index

Tags: numpy, min

I'm having some trouble with numpy and argmin. It seems as if argmin is returning the index of the maximum element. This sample code might clarify the case:

```
for i in range(20):                
            indmin = np.argmin(M[n-1, 1:-1])
            print("M[n-1, indmin] = ", M[n-1, indmin])

            print("indmin = ", indmin)

            M[n-1, indmin] = inf
```

The output of this piece of code is:

```
M[n-1, indmin] =  5.806069439930625
indmin =  1150
M[n-1, indmin] =  100000000.0
indmin =  1150
M[n-1, indmin] =  100000000.0
indmin =  1150
M[n-1, indmin] =  100000000.0
indmin =  1150
...
```

M[n-1,-1:1] contains values ranging approximately from 0 to 15. What's happening here?

Edit:
n = 813;
inf = 100000000

Link to M dump:
[http://www.mediafire.com/file/wjbk11tiafjo3do/probarray/file][1]

Comment: Can you provide `M` so we can test your code?

Comment: It would be easier for someone to help you if you provided a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Yes, of course. I added a link to an M dump in my question and the corresponding value of n.

Comment: Please, let me know if you have any problem loading M (I double checked it in my computer before uploading)

Comment: The loop does not depend on i, is this the actual code that you ran?

Comment: @PierredeBuyl Yes, it is. The idea is replace the minimum value of the array M by inf. In every iteration the minimum value should be a diferent one, since its previous position has been filled with inf. However, it seems as if this update is overlooked by np.argmin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
for i in range(20):                
            indmin = np.argmin(M[n-1, 1:-1])
            print("M[n-1, indmin] = ", M[n-1, indmin])

            print("indmin = ", indmin)

            M[n-1, indmin+1] = inf # correction, the argmin was taken with an offset of 1
```

The argument to argmin is `M[n-1, 1:-1]` so the index you obtain is *not* one that matches the indexing of `M`. There is a shift of 1.